# Paypal Webhook Events always on Pending even if response 200

Tags: javascript, c#, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-webhooks

I have configured a Paypal webhook that catches some events some of which are **Payment.Sale.Completed, Billing.Subscription.Cancelled** and so on, the following happens:

- I Create a subscription
- The subscription is paid sucessfully
- The webhook sends ("after eternity even in live Environment") the event to my api
- My api does everithing correctly and returns 200 or Ok() to Paypal but still the Paypal webhook on the dashboard remains in a Pending state.

> **One thing worth mentioning is that the icon of the webhook event is not like in the immage down its a orange checkmark ✓ and after some days it changes to Failure with a red checkmark ✓ icon so it doesn't even have the ! icon. here an example: [image: Examlpe]**

I have looked into the paypal developer community but there usually they tend to not even answer the user questions.

I event tried to conntact paypal tough and it wont let me send neighter a ticket nor an email.

Is there any step i need to take or that i am missing?

Here is an example of the checkbox when it actually has some issues with ! as an icon.
[image: The image is not mine.]

Answer (score 0):

Those screenshots are just different versions of the same interface, one is older.

The only thing required for Webhook delivery to move from Pending -> Completed is an HTTP 200 response back from the URL it's posted to. There is nothing else.

If you are certain you are responding HTTP 200 for all those events, you'll need to contact PayPal for support as only they can look into it further on their end, but I can't imagine what the initial research would be other than that they're simply not receiving the 200 response back when posting to your webhook endpoint URL.

If you set up a webhook listener to some third party test site such as https://webhook.site/ , I imagine it will work as expected.